# How the B+ tree actually works when order by some fields other than primary key?

Tags: database, indexing, b-tree

If the database uses B+tree, and we want to execute a sql query something like
`select * from x order by y`

I think that if the y is the primary, the B+ tree will be very fast, as you can just use the leaf node.

But what happens when the y is not the primary key, the DBMS still need to sort the whole database, is that right? And this is not trivial in my opinion.

And one guess is that if the y is primary key, the sql query will be much faster if y is other field, is that true?

I just think it is a very natural question, but I just found this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/405631/how-do-b-trees-used-in-databases-sort-data-based-on-different-fields.

And still quite confused..

Comment: You assume primary keys are always a clustered index, and that is definitely not the case (some DBMSes don't even have clustered indexes).

Comment: There's no single answer possible, because it depends on the specific database, how the table was defined, and what kinds of optimizations are being applied. Deciding whether to use a sort or an index scan depends on whether an extra lookup is required. If the table is stored in one b-tree, clustered by primary key 'y', with no extra lookup to find the whole row, the index scan is likely to be faster than a sort. The only way to know for sure is to display the query execution plan, but the plan can change over time as more rows are added and analysis is performed.